# How to read in tab delimited data in R and immediately make a matrix from the data?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have some simple data that I need in matrix format for downstream calculations. My data is as follows:

[image: my sample pic]

...and I want to do something like this to read in the data and label the dimensions:

```
d <- read.delim("test_data.txt",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
d <- as.matrix(???)
rownames(d) <- (???)
colnames(d) <- (???)
```

Everytime I try to fill in my '???' I get different errors or unusual results. I tried this method as well:

```
myMatrix = as.matrix(d)
heatmap(d)
```

...but get the error: Error in heatmap(myMatrix) : 'x' must be a numeric matrix

Can someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: You probably want `as.matrix`, not `matrix`.

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvote, I asked a very specific question with both graphics and code as support. I only asked after searching for a long time on the web and trying various alternatives in R. Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried your suggestion and incorporated my error message in my original question...

Comment: Before converting anything, try running `summary(d)` or `str(d)` on your data frame. This will tell you if you have any character or factor columns messing up your data. `as.matrix` will coerce everything in the data frame to the one mode, so you want to make sure everything really is numeric before doing this.

Comment: summary(d) returns Length=6, Class:character, Mode:character, and boxplot metrics. str(d) says that my first column is 'chr' and the rest 'num'.   I have labels for each column and row, and I think I need to somehow define these as text labels when generating the matrix so it doesn't confuse these as numeric entries?

Comment: A few tips for asking R questions here: (1) Images/screenshots of data are essentially useless, and many folks will consider them actively obnoxious, (2) Instead, provide a reproducible example with data and code the produces the error. The functions `head`, `dput` and `str` may be useful to that end.

Comment: Try `d <- read.delim("test_data.txt",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE , row.names = 1 ) ; d <- as.matrix(d) ; heatmap(d)`

Comment: Thanks for the tip Joran

Comment: @jake9115 welcome. Please use `dput` to show the structure and content of your data next time. Saves guesswork! :-)

Comment: I'll be sure do to so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make a reproducible example:

```
tab <- read.delim(text="Sample1,Sample2,Sample3
ID_A,4,1,6
ID_B,8,4,4
ID_C,7,5,7
ID_D,9,5,2
ID_E,0,0,3
", sep=",", row.names=1,header=TRUE)
```

Now you can just use `as.matrix`:

```
mat <- as.matrix(tab)
```

and then:

```
heatmap(mat, margins=c(10,10))
```

gives you:

[image]

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer!